# Do we want sociology questions to be on topic

Tags: discussion, on-topic

[Creating order in a settlement](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/5/72)

This question is squarely in the wheelhouse of Sociology.  While I can see that understanding this would be important to worldbuilding it does not to be on-topic.

Should it be?  Do we have any way to create guidelines for what types of sociology questions are acceptable and which should be closed?

Answer (score 13):

Sociology *related to world-building* should be on-topic here.  In fact, while we haven't seen a lot of it, it's one of the things that attracted me to the site.

I think questions that ask how having technology X would affect how communities behave is certainly on-topic.  For example, a world in which teleporters are as common as phone booths once were would vastly change how people and goods move, how breaking news is reported, how calamities are fought, even how wars are fought -- that stuff's all part of the world's context.  Questions digging into the sociological aspects of that should be as welcome as ones digging into the technical or economic aspects.

Of course, those questions still need to meet all our other expectations of questions -- not too broad, etc.  "What would be the sociological effects of teleporters?" is too broad; I meant that as a category, not an actual question.

Comment: I do not disagree here but the question linked is "What one concept/ideology is most important in a group of people to encourage them to stop acting as individuals and begin acting in the interest of the whole settlement?"  that isnt about any specific technology or worldbuilding aspect its straight sociology.

Comment: @Chad That question is too broad but just because it is too broad doesn't mean all questions similar to it would be too broad.

Comment: @Chad I'm talking about scope; "too broad" is a different dimension.  Any question within our scope still has to be narrow enough, not an opinion poll, etc.

Answer (score 2):

World building is a very broad topic in many ways.  There could be any number of questions that are relevant, and as long as the OP can show *how* a question is relevant, it should be allowed.

As to sociology questions, any world inhabited by sentient beings would have to have some sort of description of its society (or lack thereof), and questions that help the OP define a society should be allowed.